# Combo box refresh after click button event

Tags: asp.net

I have a combobox binded to a stored procedure which pulls in Years

the click event button deletes whichever year is selected and that works as I can confirm the record is actually deleted on the back end in the database. But after the delete the combo box doesnt refresh and still shows the old record. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the data again and call `combo.DataBind()` or delete the item yourself.